# jQuery event attach to an array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to bind an event to select elements where each select element is turned it to a jquery-selectbox element
(https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox)

```
var selectBoxes = [];
var selectElements = [];
$('.select').each(function (index, element) {
    //Instantiates selectbox plugin (https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox) 
    selectBoxes[index] = new SelectBox($(element), settings = {});
    selectElements[index] = selectBoxes[index].getSelectElement(); //gets the particular select element

    //Binding a close event to perform some tasks
    $(selectElements[index]).bind('close', function (el) { 
        //Doing something here
    });
});
```

Adding a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/L3dwtVl4rjn2BKBe43x5?p=preview

When I choose an option in a selectbox, the jquery event bound above is triggering as many select element is there. In my case, I have 3 select elements, so its triggering thrice.

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why aren't you initializing with $(".select").selectBox({
//options JSON here
})

Comment: is `.select` a `<select>` - sometimes it also helps to see the HTML related and its parents for a MVE here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What you have appears to be the same as `$('.select').selectBox({}).on('close',function(el){});` here...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have tried it, but its triggering thrice (in my case 3 elements). So I have initiated the object out of the Class and tried to bind an event by getting the specific select element using selectBoxes[index].getSelectElement();

Comment: `.bind('event',function)` is an alias for `.on('event',function)` - so your issue falls into "we need to see the HTML" here I believe to help isolate the challenge

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Added a plunker please review, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the plugin event handler, note the index as it fires on each.  It fires on blur etc. if you read the code.  Change is more reliable but the index is still off somehow.

```js
let selB = $('.select').selectBox({});
selB.on('close.selectbox', function(el, triggerData) {
  console.log($(this).html(), triggerData);
  console.log($(this).index('.select'));
});
selB.on('change.selectbox', function(el, triggerData) {
  console.log($(this).html(), triggerData);
  console.log($(this).index('.select'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectbox/1.2.0/jquery.selectBox.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectbox/1.2.0/jquery.selectBox.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
  <option>oneer0</option>
  <option>oneer1</option>
  <option>oneer2</option>
  <option>oneer3</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
  <option>Toneer0</option>
  <option>Toneer1</option>
  <option>Toneer2</option>
  <option>Toneer3</option>
  <option>Toneer4</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
  <option>T3oneer0</option>
  <option>T3oneer1</option>
  <option>T3oneer2</option>
  <option>T3oneer3/option>
    <option>T3oneer4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate your time and effort, Will go for other maintained plugins.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the plugin docs you are overcomplicating this

Try replacing everything you have with

```
$('select').selectBox(/* options*/).close(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Note that plugin doesn't appear to have been maintained for a very long time